# jQuery UI Slider Problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, slider

I have been using jQuery sliders for about a week now without issues in my project, but I just hit an issue.

1. I am adding 3 sliders to my page
2. All 3 are added exact same way (like this):

   ```
   $('#slider_id').slider({value:100,'slide':function(e, ui){// some code}});
   ```
3. 2 work properly
4. One does not work (it gives me a fiebug error `'f is undefined'`) when I drag the slider handle

The only glaring difference I can see is that the one giving the error is inside of a jQuery UI dialog(). Interestingly, when I place it outside of the dialog, it works!

So, wondering if there are known issues with sliders inside dialogs, and/or if there are any workarounds.

Thanks

**MORE INFO**

1. If I *don't set* the dialog **autoOpen:false** and slide the slider it works
2. If I *don't set* the dialog **autoOpen:false** but then *close it immediately* then reopen, **slider DOES NOT work** (same error as above)

Comment: When you say all 3 are added the same way, the IDs are still unique, correct?

Comment: a specific example would be nice.

Comment: @codedude - would like to - but code is trapped behind login system etc. literally thousands of lines of code. Like I said though, it works outside of the dialog() so it does indeed work (unless inside dialog). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error in a similar situation, second slider on page inside a dialog. The error was cause for me by a line setting the sliders value to NaN, after the dialog was opened.